# Django update field value after submit

Tags: python, django, formview

I am new here and in Django. But I need your help :)

I have created a search page using ListView,FormMixin class and a simple FormView :

```
class Search(ListView,FormMixin):
   template_name = "users/search.html"
   form_class = SearchForm

   def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
     """To get results"""

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     return SearchFormView.as_view()(request)
```

And

```
 class SearchFormView(FormView):
   template_name = 'users/search.html'
   form_class    = SearchForm

   def get_success_url(self):
     return reverse_lazy('users:search')

   def get_initial(self):
     if 'keySearch' in self.request.session:
       for k in self.request.session.pop('keySearch'):
         initial[k] = self.request.session.pop(k)

     return initial

   def form_valid(self, form):
      print "Form valid" 
      request = form.cleaned_data
      print "Search field {}".format(request)
      for k,v in request.iteritems():
        self.request.session[k]=v
      self.request.session['keySearch']=request.keys()
      return super(SearchFormView,self).form_valid(form)
```

But everytime, I submit the form, the "search" field is blanked. My aim is to keep in the field, the user input and display the keyword and the results of the search in the same time. I guess I am not using the get_initial method in a good way.

Moreover, I am sorry for this dirty code. I hope you have the solution and any comments would be great :)

Best regards

Comment: You need to prefill your empty form before sending it to the user. `form_data = {'form_field': 'prefilled_form_field_data'}` `form = YourForm(initial=form_data)` `return render(request, "template.html", {'form': form})`

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the form values and send them again when you render the template, could try it like this if it's useful :

```
class SearchFormView(View):
    template_name='users/search.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        valid_form = yourForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name,{
                                                    "valid_form" : valid_form,

                                                    })
```